# UIPageControl to show current page

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I made a `PageViewController` to switch between different View Controllers, and i'd like to show which page we see. I added a `pageControl`, and gave it the following code.

```
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
pageControl.numberOfPages = pages.count
```

The complete code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewControllerSportinfrastructuur: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!

var pageViewController: UIPageViewController!
let pages = ["PageOneViewController", "PageTwoViewController"]

//MARK: - page view controller data source
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    if let index = pages.indexOf(viewController.restorationIdentifier!) {
        if index > 0 {
            return viewControllerAtIndex(index - 1)
        }
    }

    return nil
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    if let index = pages.indexOf(viewController.restorationIdentifier!) {
        if index < pages.count - 1 {
            return viewControllerAtIndex(index + 1)
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> UIViewController? {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(pages[index])
    return vc
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyPageViewController") {
        self.addChildViewController(vc)
        self.view.addSubview(vc.view)

        pageViewController = vc as! UIPageViewController
        pageViewController.dataSource = self
        pageViewController.delegate = self
        pageViewController.setViewControllers([viewControllerAtIndex(0)!], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

        pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        pageControl.numberOfPages = pages.count
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what code i should use to set up the current page? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: found the answer already!

I added `pageControl.currentPage = index` in following functions:

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    if let index = pages.indexOf(viewController.restorationIdentifier!) {
        pageControl.currentPage = index
        if index > 0 {
            return viewControllerAtIndex(index - 1)
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

And did the same for the `viewControllerAfterViewController` func!

Comment: Would not recommend to base your code on this if you have scrolling enabled. In case you have scrolling enabled a user may scroll not until the end or until the end and fast back and in this cases I spotted that these methods will actually mess up with what's the current viewController. If you want to avoid this glitch better use UIPageViewController delegate method func pageViewController didFinishAnimating and while checking for "completed" retrieve the current view controller as pageViewController.viewControllers.first

Answer (score 0):

The `UIPageViewController` provides a default `UIPageControl` - I would recommend to make use of it if you don't have particular custom requirements.

In order to show it you need to implement the following two optional methods in your `UIPageViewControllerDataSource`:

```
func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return n //number of view controllers
}

func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return i //index of the visible view controller
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Set `pageViewController.delegate = self`, implement protocol `UIPageViewControllerDelegate`

and use on of these methods to set `self.pageControl.currentPage = ...`

```
optional func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
 willTransitionToViewControllers pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController])

optional func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
              didFinishAnimating finished: Bool,
         previousViewControllers previousViewControllers: [UIViewController],
             transitionCompleted completed: Bool)
```